# WSO2 ESB 5.0 Error trying to consume message from message store

Tags: wso2, jms, apache-synapse, wso2-message-broker, wso2-esb

I'm using **WSO2 ESB 5.0 with MB as a feature**, on the same instance.

I'm getting an error **StorableMessage cannot be found**:

> ERROR - JmsConsumer [msg-store-C-1] cannot receive message from store. Error:Could not deserialize message: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.synapse.message.store.impl.commons.**StorableMessage** cannot be found **by andes_3.1.1**

Just a single line, without stacktrace.

Probably It's missing some .jar on lib, or it has wrong version, but I have no idea which is.

**Does someone know what is missing/wrong?**

**Or, what should I check?**

Thanks

**Edited:**

Using WSO2 Message Broker as a separate instance works just fine..

Regardless of same or separate instances, I'm using MessageStore and MessageProcessor:

```
<messageStore class="org.apache.synapse.message.store.impl.jms.JmsStore" name="msg-store" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <parameter name="store.jms.destination">msg-queue</parameter>
  <parameter name="store.producer.guaranteed.delivery.enable">false</parameter>
  <parameter name="store.jms.cache.connection">false</parameter>
  <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial">org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory</parameter>
  <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url">repository/conf/jndi.properties</parameter>
  <parameter name="store.jms.JMSSpecVersion">1.1</parameter>
</messageStore>
<messageProcessor class="org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.sampler.SamplingProcessor" messageStore="msg-store" name="msg-processor" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <parameter name="sequence">delivery-or-death-sequence</parameter>
  <parameter name="interval">1</parameter>
  <parameter name="is.active">true</parameter>
  <parameter name="concurrency">1</parameter>
</messageProcessor>
```

Comment: Did you use the message processor to consume messages from the store?

Comment: Yep, question edited..

Answer (score 0):

From the first place it is not recommended to install MB features into ESB itself. First start up the MB as a separate instance. Then copy all the MB libs to ESB lib directory as mentioned in the documentation. Try that out first. If you can provide me your synapse configs, I can look into  this issue further more.

Comment: I'll try the copy approach.

Comment: By the way, can you point out where in documentation, suggests it's not recommended to install MB as an ESB feature?